# Access to a vector in cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab

`C` is a cell consisting of some vectors:

```
C = {[1, 2], [2, 3]};
```

I want to read the first entry of the first vector in `C`. But I can not use the following:

```
C{1}[2]
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

How can I make it read the value?

Comment: matlab uses `()` to access elements of vectors, not `[]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can access individual elements of matrices in cell array like this:

```
C{n,m}(ii,jj);
```

This will give you element `(ii,jj)` of the matrix at index `(n,m)` of the cell array.

Hence, for your particular example,

`val = C{1,1}(1,1)` (or `val = C{1}(1)`)

will assign the value of the first element of the first vector in the cell array to the variable `val`.

Comment: It is better not to use [`i` and `j` as variables in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: I know, but I can't help it, it's too much of a habit just using `i` and `j`. I changed it to the most (I think) commonly used alternatives, `ii` and `jj`.

Comment: I prefer to use 1i and 1j if the imaginary unit is needed as [shoelzer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14861015/3058047) pointed out. In my opinion, it is the most readable and consistent solution to this issue